# Force label line wrap

Tags: python, size, gtk3

I'm using a Gtk.Label within a tooltip to display text. The text is usually rather short, but does occasionally become very long, in which case the label expands horizontally to fill the entire screen width, which results in a ridiculously wide tooltip. Is there a way to force the label's text into more lines?

I had two ideas:

1) set the label's maximum width. Gtk doesn't seem to support this.

2) set the label's maximum line length. Gtk doesn't seem to support this either.

Which means I'm fresh out of ideas. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [gtk.Label.set_line_wrap](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtklabel.html#method-gtklabel--set-line-wrap) combined with [gtk.Label.set_max_width_chars](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtklabel.html#method-gtklabel--set-max-width-chars).

Example:

```py
label.set_line_wrap(True)
label.set_max_width_chars(20)
```